# Java - Calling a method from another class with array as parameter

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Hi I've been working on a homework assignment to make a 3D tic tac toe game without a GUI in Java. I can't get my check for a winner method to run. I've tried a bunch of different formats but I always get an error:

```
method checkForWinner in class TicTacToe3D cannot be applied to given types;
```

Here is my code:

```
    // Java 2 Assignment 1 Tic Tac Toe 3D
    // Make a 3D tic tac toe game for two players with no GUI
    // Check if there is a winner, loser, continue playing, or draw (no more       

    moves left on board)
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TicTacToe3D
    {
    String [][][]board = new String [3][3][3]; //3 dimensional array for tic         

   tac toe board
final static String WIN = "Player 1 has won the game!";
final static String WIN2 = "Player 2 has won the game!";
final static String DRAW = "There are no moves left. It is a draw.";
//final static boolean CONTINUE  = true; 
final static String CONTINUE = "Next player.";
boolean gameOver = false;
static int player = 0;
// constructor to initialize array and playersChoice
public TicTacToe3D()
{
    initializeBoard();
} // end constructor

// Create new board
public void initializeBoard()
{
    int i, j, k;
    // loop through array rows
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        // loop thourgh array columns
        for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            // loop through array diagonally
            for ( k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                board[i][j][k] = " ";
            } // end inner for loop
        } // end for loop
    } // end outer for loop
} // end method initialieBoard

// print tic tac toe board
public void printBoard() 
{
    // first board
    System.out.println("Top Board");
    System.out.println("  1   2   3");
    System.out.println("1" + board[0][0][0] + "  | " + board[0][0][1] + " | " + board[0][0][2]);  
    System.out.println("---+----+---");
    System.out.println("2" + board[0][1][0] + "  | " + board[0][1][1] + " | " + board[0][1][2]);  
    System.out.println("---+----+---");
    System.out.println("3" + board[0][2][0] + "  | " + board[0][2][1] + " | " + board[0][2][2]);  
    System.out.println();

    //second board
    System.out.println("Middle Board");
    System.out.println("  1   2   3");
    System.out.println("1" + board[1][0][0] + "  | " + board[1][0][1] + " | " + board[1][0][2]);  
    System.out.println("---+----+---");
    System.out.println("2" + board[1][1][0] + "  | " + board[1][1][1] + " | " + board[1][1][2]);  
    System.out.println("---+----+---");
    System.out.println("3" + board[1][2][0] + "  | " + board[1][2][1] + " | " + board[1][2][2]);  
    System.out.println();

    // third board
    System.out.println("Bottom Board");
    System.out.println("  1   2   3");
    System.out.println("1" + board[2][0][0] + "  | " + board[2][0][1] + " | " + board[2][0][2]);  
    System.out.println("---+----+---");
    System.out.println("2" + board[2][1][0] + "  | " + board[2][1][1] + " | " + board[2][1][2]);  
    System.out.println("---+----+---");
    System.out.println("3" + board[2][2][0] + "  | " + board[2][2][1] + " | " + board[2][2][2]);    
    System.out.println();

} // end method printBoard

// method to make a move
public void makeAMove()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    int row = 0, column = 0, pla = 0;
    char piece;
    int pieceX = 0;
    int pieceO = 0;

    System.out.printf("Enter 1 for player 1 or 2 for player 2.: ", player);
    player = input.nextInt();

//  while( != gameOver)
//  {
        if (player == 1) 
        {
            System.out.println("Player 1 enter board number (0-2): ");
            pla = input.nextInt();
            if ( (pla >= 0) || (pla <= 2))
            {
                System.out.println("Player 1 enter row number (0-2): ");
                row = input.nextInt();  

                if ( (row >= 0) || (row <= 2))
                {
                    System.out.println("Player 1 enter column number (0-2): ");
                    column = input.nextInt();   
                } 

                else if ( ( pla < 0 ) || ( pla > 2))
                {
                    System.out.println(" Please only enter a number between 0 and 2 for a board number." );
                    pla = input.nextInt();  
                }

                else if ( ( row < 0 ) || ( row > 2))
                {
                    System.out.println(" Please only enter a number between 0 and 2 for a row number." );
                    row = input.nextInt();  
                }

                else if ( ( column < 0 ) || ( column > 2))
                {
                    System.out.println(" Please only enter a number between 0 and 2 for a column number." );
                    column = input.nextInt();
                }

            //  piece = "X";
                board[pla][row][column] = "X";
                printBoard();
    //          checkForWinner();
            } // end if statement
        } // end if statement 


            else if (player == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Player 2 enter board number (0-2): ");
                pla = input.nextInt();

                if ( (pla >= 0) || (pla <= 2))
                {
                    System.out.println("Player 2 enter row number (0-2): ");
                    row = input.nextInt();  
                }
                    else if  ( (row >= 0) || (row <= 2))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player 2 enter column number (0-2): ");
                        column = input.nextInt();   
                    } 

                    else if ( ( pla < 0 ) || ( pla > 2))
                    {   
                        System.out.println(" Please only enter a number between 0 and 2 for a board number." );
                        pla = input.nextInt();  
                    }

                    else if ( ( row < 0 ) || ( row > 2))
                    {
                        System.out.println(" Please only enter a number between 0 and 2 for a row number." );
                        row = input.nextInt();  
                    }

                    else if ( ( column < 0 ) || ( column > 2))
                    {
                        System.out.println(" Please only enter a number between 0 and 2 for a column number." );
                        column = input.nextInt();
                    }

                    board[pla][row][column] = "O";
                    printBoard();
        //          checkForWinner();   
                } // end else if statement
//      } // end while statement
        } // end method makeAMove

    public String checkForWinner( String[][][]board )
    {
        // check win for rows, columns, and diagonally

        // check diagonals going down left
        if ( board[0][0][0] == "X" && board[0][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;

        }
            else if ( board[0][0][0] == "O" && board[0][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][0][0] == "X" && board[0][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;

        }
            else if ( board[0][0][0] == "O" && board[0][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][0][0] == "X" && board[0][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;

        }
            else if ( board[0][0][0] == "O" && board[0][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][0][0] == "X" && board[0][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;

        }
            else if ( board[0][0][0] == "O" && board[0][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;        
            }

        else if ( board[0][0][0] == "X" && board[0][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][0][0] == "O" && board[0][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][0][0] == "X" && board[0][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][0][0] == "O" && board[0][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][0][0] == "X" && board[0][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][0][0] == "O" && board[0][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
            {   
                return WIN2;    
            }

        else if ( board[0][0][0] == "X" && board[0][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][0][0] == "O" && board[0][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][0][0] == "X" && board[0][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][0][0] == "O" && board[0][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][0][0] == "X" && board[1][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][0][0] == "O" && board[1][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][0][0] == "X" && board[1][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][0][0] == "O" && board[1][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][0][0] == "X" && board[1][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][0][0] == "O" && board[1][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][0][0] == "X" && board[1][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][0][0] == "O" && board[1][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][0][0] == "X" && board[1][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][0][0] == "O" && board[1][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][0][0] == "X" && board[1][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][0][0] == "O" && board[1][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][0][0] == "X" && board[1][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][0][0] == "O" && board[1][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][0][0] == "X" && board[1][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
        {   
            return WIN;
        }
        else if ( board[1][0][0] == "O" && board[1][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
        {   
            return WIN2;
        }

        else if ( board[1][0][0] == "X" && board[1][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][0][0] == "O" && board[1][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][0][0] == "X" && board[2][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][0][0] == "O" && board[2][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][0][0] == "X" && board[2][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][0][0] == "O" && board[2][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][0][0] == "X" && board[2][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][0][0] == "O" && board[2][0][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][0][0] == "X" && board[2][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][0][0] == "O" && board[2][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][0][0] == "X" && board[2][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][0][0] == "O" && board[2][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][0][0] == "X" && board[2][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][0][0] == "O" && board[2][0][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][0][0] == "X" && board[2][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][0][0] == "O" && board[2][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[0][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][0][0] == "X" && board[2][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][0][0] == "O" && board[2][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[1][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][0][0] == "X" && board[2][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][0][0] == "O" && board[2][0][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][0][0] == board[2][2][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        // check diagonals going up right

        else if ( board[0][2][0] == "X" && board[0][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][2][0] == "O" && board[0][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][2][0] == "X" && board[0][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][2][0] == "O" && board[0][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][2][0] == "X" && board[0][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][2][0] == "O" && board[0][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][2][0] == "X" && board[0][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][2][0] == "O" && board[0][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][2][0] == "X" && board[0][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][2][0] == "O" && board[0][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][2][0] == "X" && board[0][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][2][0] == "O" && board[0][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][2][0] == "X" && board[0][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][2][0] == "O" && board[0][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][2][0] == "X" && board[0][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][2][0] == "O" && board[0][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[0][2][0] == "X" && board[0][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[0][2][0] == "O" && board[0][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[0][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][2][0] == "X" && board[1][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][2][0] == "O" && board[1][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][2][0] == "X" && board[1][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][2][0] == "O" && board[1][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][2][0] == "X" && board[1][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][2][0] == "O" && board[1][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][2][0] == "X" && board[1][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][2][0] == "O" && board[1][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][2][0] == "X" && board[1][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][2][0] == "O" && board[1][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][2][0] == "X" && board[1][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][2][0] == "O" && board[1][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][2][0] == "X" && board[1][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }   
            else if ( board[1][2][0] == "O" && board[1][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][2][0] == "X" && board[1][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][2][0] == "O" && board[1][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[1][2][0] == "X" && board[1][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[1][2][0] == "O" && board[1][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[1][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][2][0] == "X" && board[2][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][2][0] == "O" && board[2][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][2][0] == "X" && board[2][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][2][0] == "O" && board[2][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][2][0] == "X" && board[2][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][2][0] == "O" && board[2][2][0] == board[0][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][2][0] == "X" && board[2][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][2][0] == "O" && board[2][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][2][0] == "X" && board[2][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][2][0] == "O" && board[2][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][2][0] == "X" && board[2][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][2][0] == "O" && board[2][2][0] == board[1][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }   

        else if ( board[2][2][0] == "X" && board[2][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][2][0] == "O" && board[2][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[0][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][2][0] == "X" && board[2][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }
            else if ( board[2][2][0] == "O" && board[2][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[1][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        else if ( board[2][2][0] == "X" && board[2][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
        {
            return WIN;
        }   
            else if ( board[2][2][0] == "O" && board[2][2][0] == board[2][1][1] && board[2][2][0] == board[2][0][2] )
            {
                return WIN2;
            }

        // check rows
        for ( int y = 0; y < 3; y++ )
        {
            for ( int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
            {   
                if ( board[y][z][0] == "X" && board[y][z][0] == board[y][z][1] && board[y][z][1] == board[y][z][2] ) 
                {
                    return WIN;
                }

                else if (board[y][z][0] == "O" && board[y][z][0] == board[y][z][1] && board[y][z][1] == board[y][z][2])
                {
                    return WIN2;
                }
            } // end for loop
        } // end for loop 

        // check columns
        for ( int a = 0; a < 3; a++ )
        {
            for ( int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
            {
                for ( int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    if ( board[0][a][b] == "X" && board[0][a][b] == board[1][a][b] && board[1][a][b] == board[2][a][b] )
                    {
                        return WIN;
                    }
                    else if ( board[0][a][b] == "O" && board[0][a][b] == board[1][a][b] && board[1][a][b] == board[2][a][b] )
                    {
                        return WIN2;
                    }
                } // end inner for loop 
            } // end for loop    
        } // end outer for loop 

        // check for draw or continue
        for ( int d = 0; d < 3; ++d )
        {
            for ( int c = 0; c < 3; ++c )
            {
                for ( int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                {
                    if ( board[d][c][z] == " " )
                    {
                        return CONTINUE; // game is not finished
                    }
                } // end inner for loop 
            } // end for loop

        } // outer for loop

        return DRAW; // game is a draw

    } // end method checkForWinner

   } // end class TicTacToe3D
```

And:

```
     public class TicTacToe3DTest 
     {
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
    TicTacToe3D game = new TicTacToe3D();
    game.makeAMove()
    game.printBoard();
    game.checkForWinner();

} // end main method    
} // end class TicTacToe3DTest
```

Any feedback on how I can get the method `checkForWinner()` to run with test class for `array` is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The key to the error is that when calling a method, your method call **must** match that of one of the declared method signatures.

You've declared `checkForWinner(...)` to take a 3D array parameter:

```
public String checkForWinner( String[][][]board ) {
    // .....
```

But when you are calling it, you do so without passing in any array:

```
checkForWinner(); // ..... no array passed in!
```

A possible solution: since you're only using one class here, you could remove the array from the method declaration and always test the array field in the class.

In other words, change this:

```
public String checkForWinner( String[][][]board )
```

to this:

```
public String checkForWinner()
```

As an aside, I would have this method return a `boolean`, not a `String`. Or if you need to return several states have the method return an enum constant.

Comment: I disagree with it returning a boolean, simply because the current setup also handles checking for a draw, making 3 outcomes available. Edit: Actually 4 when you consider it also specifies which player won.

Comment: @OblivionCreations: then I'd have it return an enum. A String is a dangerous thing to use in this situation, an "anti-pattern".

Comment: I'd definitely go with enum, I enjoy the compiler knowing what valid values it can return